# How to create global function for all .JSLIB files?

Tags: unity, javascript, webgl

I can't understand how to work with `.jslib` files. I don't understand the syntax of this type of file. Also I couldn't find any easy explanation of it

The problem started when I tried to make two functions global for all `.jslib` files:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
function StrJSToStrCS (str) {
    const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
    const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
    stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
    return buffer;
}

/**
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
function StrCSToStrJS (str) {
    return UTF8ToString(str);
}
```

What I already tried:

- To define these two functions in the same file

  ```
  function StrJSToStrCS (str) {
      const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
      const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
      stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
      return buffer;
  }

  function StrCSToStrJS (str) {
      return UTF8ToString(str);
  }

  const lib = {
      Hello: function () {
          return StrJSToStrCS('HELLO WORLD!');
      },

      ConsoleLog: function (str) {
          console.log(StrCSToStrJS(str));
      }
  };

  mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, lib);
  ```
- To define these two functions in `script` tag in `.html` after reading [this](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#javascript-limits-in-library-files). If it's important the script tag I inserted at the bottom of `body` tag

  ```html
  <script>
      function StrJSToStrCS (str) {
          const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
          const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
          stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
          return buffer;
      }

      function StrCSToStrJS (str) {
          return UTF8ToString(str);
      }
  </script>
  ```

  ```js
  const lib = {
      Hello: function () {
          return StrJSToStrCS('HELLO WORLD!');
      },

      ConsoleLog: function (str) {
          console.log(StrCSToStrJS(str));
      }
  };

  mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, lib);
  ```
- To define these functions in `.jspre` file after reading [this](https://medium.com/@depanther/unity-webgl-secrets-b6ddf214f1fd)

  > the .jspre files are added to the build using the --pre-js option, while the .jslib are added using the --js-library option

  `.jspre` file:

  ```js
  function StrJSToStrCS (str) {
      const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
      const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
      stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
      return buffer;
  }

  function StrCSToStrJS (str) {
      return UTF8ToString(str);
  }
  ```

  `.jslib` file:

  ```js
  const lib = {
      Hello: function () {
          return StrJSToStrCS('HELLO WORLD!');
      },

      ConsoleLog: function (str) {
          console.log(StrCSToStrJS(str));
      }
  };

  mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, lib);
  ```
- To simply define these functions as methods in the same object:

  ```js
  const lib = {
      StrJSToStrCS: function(str) {
          const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
          const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
          stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
          return buffer;
      },

      StrCSToStrJS: function(str) {
          return UTF8ToString(str);
      },

      Hello: function() {
          return this.StrJSToStrCS('HELLO WORLD!');
      },

      ConsoleLog: function(str) {
          console.log(this.StrCSToStrJS(str));
      }
  }

  mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, lib);
  ```

But whatever I do, he writes every time in console that `StrJSToStrCS/StrCSToStrJS` is not defined

I don't understand at all why the last method doesn't work. Isn't `lib` just a simple object?

Is it possible to make these two functions global for all `.jslib` files?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the answer!

In `.jspre` file I had to write:

```js
Module.StrJSToStrCS = function(str) {
    const bufferSize = lengthBytesUTF8(str) + 1;
    const buffer = _malloc(bufferSize);
    stringToUTF8(str, buffer, bufferSize);
    return buffer;
}

Module.StrCSToStrJS = function(str) {
    return UTF8ToString(str);
}
```

and then in `.jslib` file call these functions like this:

```js
const lib = {
    Hello: function() {
        return gameInstance.Module.StrJSToStrCS('HELLO WORLD!');
    },

    ConsoleLog: function(str) {
        console.log(gameInstance.Module.StrCSToStrJS(str));
    }
}

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, lib);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the official documentation very useful when I was working with webgl and unity and also has some examples.
[Interaction with browser scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

Its a library file and has to be placed in Plugins folder.

In case this doesn't help, please post the Unity side of things also to get more understanding.

Comment: I already read the official documentation and there is only simple examples. I don't have a problem with calling JS functions from CS and vice versa. Please read my question attentively. In short I need global JS function for several JSLIB files